# Diophantine equation with class group techniques

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, prime-factorization, ideal-class-group

Solve in integers $x^2 - x + 10 = y^3$. (You may use the fact that the class number of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-39})$ is $4$ and that its ring of integers is $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{-39}}{2}\right]$).

Approach: after factoring we get (in terms of ideals) $(x-\frac{1 + \sqrt{-39}}{2})(x - \frac{1 - \sqrt{-39}}{2}) = (y)^3$ and aim to obtain that the factors on the left are cubes of ideals (then since $3$ and the class number $4$ are coprime it would be easy to finish). If the factors are coprime we are fine, but if they are not, then a common prime factor ideal must divide $(1+\sqrt{-39}) = (2, \frac{1 + \sqrt{-39}}{2})^2(2,\frac{3 + \sqrt{-39}}{2})(5, \frac{1 + \sqrt{-39}}{2})$ (the factorization was done by Dedekind's theorem on $(2)$ and $(5)$). Any idea how to finish?

Any help appreciated!

EDIT: Just for the sake of curiosity, can anyone find an elementary way to solve this? It should be the case that this equation has no solutions, so it is not unlikely that an elementary proof exists.

Comment: Hi - Just to clarify your reasoning, where did your $1 + \sqrt{-39}$ come from, as a common factor?

Comment: @JohnM calculation error it seems... actually the difference of the two ideals is just $\sqrt{-39}$ and not with a $+1$, I'll try again, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it now! Actually the norm of $(\sqrt{-39})$ is $39$ and the norm of the common factor $P$ also has to divide $N((y)^3) = y^6$, so $y$ must be divisible by $3$ or $13$ and this is impossible from moduli $3^2$ and $13^2$.

(Nothing new has been used here, just turned out I had fatal calculation errors, sorry!)

Comment: You can "simplify" (short Weierstrass form) it to the elliptic curve $y^2=x^3−624$ of Mordell type, which has no integer points.

Comment: Alright, cool but can you prove in an elementary manner that this curve indeed can no integer points?

Comment: There are elementary proofs given in Conrad [notes](https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/mordelleqn1.pdf), but I haven't tried, whether or not $k=624$ is also possible in this way. On the other hand, it might be better to use some algebraic number theory.

Comment: @DietrichBurde yeah yeah I thought about this just now, $y^2 + 25^2 = x^3 + 1$ should indeed do the job!

Comment: @DietrichBurde but in order to do the transform, you need rational maps. How are you sure that transforming an elliptic curve via rational maps gives again an elliptic curve which has the same number of integral points?